# jQuery UI AutoComplete Multiple Values - how can I show the suggestion list after a space instead of a comma?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to use the AutoComplete plugin for jQuery UI, [specifically the multiple values functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) (with a local array). The goal is an 'intellisense' type effect.

The suggestion box appears ****ONLY**** after you have a comma separating your entires.

For example:

```
test1, <suggestion list appears>
```

In my case, I want the suggestion list to appear after a **SPACE**, instead of a comma, i.e.:

```
test1<space> <suggestion list appears>
```

This functionality (or lack thereof) can be seen directly on the demo page linked above, simply type 'Clojure', and the box will autocomplete with a comma, then typing another word, such as Java, will then reopen the suggestion list. If you do the same, type Clojure, delete the comma, then press space, suggestions will no longer appear.

I tried to poke into the AutoComplete code but did not see what made this happen - I am not opposed to modifying the actual jQuery UI source itself to make this happen, or use an entirely different plugin system that supports this better.

Any help is appreciated - let me know if you need more detail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the behavior of the insert by modifying the `select` event callback. If you click on "view source" on the demo page, you'll see `this.value = terms.join( ", " );` Just change that to `this.value = terms.join( " " );`

Edit:
You'll probably also want to edit the `split()` function in the demo source code:

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
```

(Remove the comma)

Comment: That's it - I was looking way deeper into this than I needed to :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

it is an old Q but I also needed this. Plain removal of the comma in split function produced wierd behaviour in my case.

> Calvin L Edit: You'll probably also want to edit the split() function in the demo source code:

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
(Remove the comma)
```

Instead of filling-in with selected value, it also concatenated original partial segment:
e.g. input letters a, aj (etc.) + space + filled-in word. Also, auto-suggestion acted wierd, instead of filtering the more letters were typed, it showed more non-related results instead.

Solution was to simply replace comma with space:

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( / \s*/ );
}
```